# visual studio sql data compare miss some table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

If i use the **Data Compare Tool** from **Visual Studio** to update the data. 
It **missed one of my Detailtable**. Has some one experience with this problem and know how to fix this?

### Visual Studio Info

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51650

Installierte Version: Professional

LightSwitch für Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0444002-02314
Microsoft LightSwitch für Visual Studio 2013

Rechtschreibprüfung für die Visual Studio 2013-Codeanalyse   06177-004-0444002-02314
Rechtschreibprüfung für die Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013-Codeanalyse

Teile des International CorrectSpell™-Rechtschreibprüfungssystems © 1993 von Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Elektronische Version lizenziert von Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Team Explorer für Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0444002-02314
Microsoft Team Explorer für Visual Studio 2013

Visual Basic 2013   06177-004-0444002-02314
Microsoft Visual Basic 2013

Visual C# 2013   06177-004-0444002-02314
Microsoft Visual C# 2013

Visual C++ 2013   06177-004-0444002-02314
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013

Visual F# 2013   06177-004-0444002-02314
Microsoft Visual F# 2013

Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - DEU   06177-004-0444002-02314
Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - DEU

Allgemeine Azure-Tools   1.3
Bietet allgemeine Dienste für die Verwendung durch Azure Mobile Services und Microsoft Azure Tools.

Application Insights Tools für Visual Studio Package   1.0
Application Insights Tools für Visual Studio

ASP.NET und Webtools   12.4.51016.0
Microsoft Web Developer Tools enthält die folgenden Komponenten:
Unterstützung beim Erstellen und Öffnen von ASP.NET-Webprojekten
Browserlink: Ein Kommunikationskanal zwischen Visual Studio und Browsern
Editor-Erweiterungen für HTML, CSS und JavaScript
Seitenprüfung: Prüfungstool für ASP.NET-Webprojekte
Gerüstbau: Ein Framework zum Erstellen und Ausführen von Codegeneratoren
Server Explorer-Erweiterungen für Microsoft Azure-Websites
Webpublishing: Erweiterungen zum Veröffentlichen von ASP.NET-Webprojekten für Hostinganbieter, lokale Server oder Microsoft Azure

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.21001.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.21010.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

CodeMaid   #114
CodeMaid is an open source Visual Studio extension to cleanup, dig through and simplify our C#, C++, F#, VB, XAML, XML, ASP, HTML, CSS, LESS, SCSS, JavaScript and TypeScript coding.

Written by Steve Cadwallader, for more information visit http://www.codemaid.net/

Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone   
Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone
Build 

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.3
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NHibernate Extension for Visual Studio 2012   1.0
Information about my package

NuGet-Paket-Manager   2.8.50926.663
NuGet-Paket-Manager in Visual Studio. Weitere Informationen zu NuGet finden Sie unter "http://docs.nuget.org/".

Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU   12.0.30626
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU

PowerShell-Tools   1.3
Führt Klassifizierungsdienste mit PowerShell durch

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio-Erweiterung zur Visualisierung aggregierter Zusammenfassungen vom PreEmptive Analytics-Produkt.

Regular Expression Tester Extension   1.0
Provides testing and management of regular expressions

Sandcastle Help File Builder   SHFB
Visual Studio integration for the Sandcastle Help File Builder.
Copyright © 2011, Eric Woodruff, All Rights Reserved.
http://SHFB.CodePlex.com

SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.41012.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Visual Studio Spell Checker   VSSpellChecker
An editor extension that checks the spelling of comments, strings, and plain text as you type.

Windows Azure Tools   2.3
Windows Azure Tools für Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - v2.3.20320.1602

Windows Installer XML Toolset   3.9.1006.0
Windows Installer XML Toolset version 3.9.1006.0
Copyright (c) Outercurve Foundation. All rights reserved.

Windows Phone 8.1 SDK-Integration   1.0
Dieses Paket integriert die Tools für das Windows Phone 8.1 SDK in die Menüs und Steuerelemente von Visual Studio.

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.
```

### Source Database

[image]

### Target Database

[image]

### Table Settings

[image]

### Schema

there is no difference beside of some StoredProcedures, my target db is a clone from my source db

Any help to fix this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: @DownVoter could you please explain your vote?

Comment: Does that table have a primary key that can be used for the compare (not just a unique column - an actual PK)? If not, that could be part of the issue. Red-Gate's Data Compare can handle it with more flexibility, but does cost for a license.

Comment: @PeterSchott Oh it has a unique column but non PK, so i will check this. thx for your advice

Comment: @PeterSchott nice, now it works fine :) If you like to earn some Points create an Answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Data Compare - Some tables missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115502/sql-data-compare-some-tables-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a Primary Key on the table (not just a unique index). I think SSDT's data compare needs that to work. If you can't do that, it's worth investing in Red-Gate's SQL Data Compare. You can specify custom columns with that tool.