# SQL Data Compare - Some tables missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

When doing a Data Compare using SQL Server Data Tools through VS 2013 pro, I have a scenario where some tables appear to be getting missed out.

What I mean by that is there is data in `TableA` on the source server but no data in the equivalent table on the destination server.

However the results window doesn't even display a row for `TableA`.

Also if I try to filter the results in the next step prior to pressing "Finish", `TableA` doesn't appear as an option to filter by. It's almost as if the table doesn't exist on the destination server. I've verified that is does by:

- Connecting through SSMS and viewing the list of tables
- Running `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables`

In both cases I can see the table is listed.

Has anyone else seen this? What am I missing?

Comment: Data can be compared only if you know what records from tables must be compared. Compareer uses PK to know what records to compare. If your table don't have a PK (or at least a unique index) it ill be missing from the tables list

Comment: Thanks Jean, that was the issue. I'm working with a DB provided by someone else and hadn't spotted that there was no PK on this table (there were actually a few others with the same issue too). Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Data can be compared only if you know what records from tables must be compared. Comparer uses PK to know what records to compare. If your table doesn't have a PK (or at least a unique index) it ill be missing from the tables list.

You can solve it by creating a PK yourself (just for comparison)

**EDIT**

1. A coworker got a hard time recently due to someone explicit excluding some tables from the comparison project and committing it to git. So check it if it's not a new project.
2. I recently was tasked to compare tables without PK and found [HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to be a new friend, also there are not unique rows in the tables and to solve it I used [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with PARTITION, see below snipet.

```
    SELECT Row_number() 
             OVER ( 
               partition BY [hashid] 
               ORDER BY [hashid]) AS RowNumber, 
           * 
    INTO   [dbo].[mytable_temp] 
    FROM   (SELECT Hashbytes('SHA2_512', (SELECT x.* 
                                          FOR xml raw)) AS [HASHID], 
                   * 
            FROM   [dbo].[mytable] AS x) AS y 

    go 

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable_temp] 
      ALTER COLUMN [hashid] VARBINARY(900) NOT NULL 

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable_temp] 
      ALTER COLUMN [rownumber] BIGINT NOT NULL 

    go 

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable_temp] 
      ADD CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY ([hashid], [rownumber]) 

    go
```

That way I can create PK based on a hash calculated with the entire row content.

Obs:. Note I'm comparing `MyTable_TEMP`and not `MyTable`. that way I can leave it untounched.

Comment: I have the same issue but the table does have a PK? It has a PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

Comment: Both tables must get some kind of "unique" column/index, Usually (idealy) a PK is unique. A CLUSTERED index is probably unique

Comment: Microsoft should give some indicator/message that certain tables need primary keys in order to compare.  The user needs more feedback on the output screen, because this was not clear when we ran the comparison.  Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 4):

The tool is case sensitive. I had to rename the schema from `core` to `Core` to get tables in that schema to show up since the other database had the name `Core`.